# How to debug undefined reference to vtable for class?

Tags: c++, debugging

Whenever there is undefined reference to function error, two things are obvious

1. Somewhere in your source code, you are referring to the function
2. The libraries/objects you are linking against doesn't have the definition for function

Using readelf and addr2line commands, we can find out if the libraries/objects we are linking against does really have function definition or not. And if they have the defined the function, we can find if the function is hidden or exposed. This way we can figure out the root cause and fix the issue.

But when it comes to vtable

1. How do we get to know which part of the source code is using the vtable? Are there any tools and debugging techniques available?

Example:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
   virtual void function(){cout<<"Base function";}
};

class Sub : public Base
{
public:
   void function(){cout<<"Sub function";}
};

int main()
{
   Base *ptr = new Sub();
   ptr->function();//when this is called, I guess vtable will be used.
   // We can say this by concept.
   // But is there anyway I can prove it is actually using vtable?
}
```

Comment: provided example code

Comment: If you are asking whether an entry of the vtable is needed: that is when a virtual function is called and in other cases. If you are asking when a reference to the vtable itself is needed: That is when the constructor is called, because it has to set a pointer to the vtable in the new object.

Comment: I found this useful https://godbolt.org/z/pb2uzk .Here it actually shows where and how vtable is being use. Anybody has any idea how godbolt is giving this compiler output (2nd tab). What tool they are using internally? I tried objdump on the generated file, its not showing any vtable reference.

Comment: In the code of `Sub::Sub` you see a reference to `vtable for Sub@GOT`. You do not see a definition of the vtable, because the compiler would emit it with the definition of the first virtual function, `function()` in your case, but you did not define it anywhere.